# Anyone Familiar With LAPACK And BLAS?

Tags: visual-c++, lapack, blas

I am a beginner and few weeks ago I still knew nothing about C++. Now I find myself in trouble installing *LAPACK*.

First, I wanted to use *VC++ 2010* to do some matrix calculation so (following someone's suggestion) I installed *Armadillo*. I found that *Armadillo* uses *LAPACK* and *BLAS* to do some matrix inverse work, and that is what put me in trouble.

I have several questions about running *LAPACK*. I already read the instructions [here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack). I downloaded all kinds of .dll and .lib file and changed their locations several time to try to compile successfully in VC++ 2010. I changed the 'Aditional Library Directories' on 'Propertie/linker/general' and added liblapack.lib in 'Additional Dependencies' at 'Propertie/linker/input'.

I am not able to understand the following:

1. Many websites say *LAPACK* should be installed somewhere, but all I could do is to download a file (folder) either named `lapack` or `lapack-3.4.1`. I could not find any install.exe in the folder. So, what does *download* mean?
2. On th website above, the *.dll* and *.lib* files should be downloaded. Where should I put them? Suppose my *VC++ 2010* is installed on `P:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0`; should I put them in this directory? Where should I put or install the *downloaded* *LAPACK* package?
3. What does a *reference BLAS* mean? If I do not use *cmake* and *mingw* to build and compile, can I still follow the download steps provided on that website?

This is kind of long. I searched every forum and tried every possible method but I am still confused. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me epxlain at least a part of my question. Thanks!

Comment: Although a bit too wide, it raises some very basic questions a beginner could have when jumping into matrix libraries like armadillo. It could be useful to other beginners that do not know very much about it.

Answer (score 4):

Whoa there, slow down, for a beginner you're in way too deep.  So you listened to someone who suggested 'use Armadillo' then went off and left you to your own devices !  It's no wonder you are lost, lonely and confused.

What, in Armadillo, do you need ?  If you want to do matrix computations with C++ on Windows you've got a few options which don't involve Armadillo.  These options include

- [Intel's MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/) -- which may cost you money.
- [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) -- which includes an implementation of (some of) BLAS under the name uBLAS.
- [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).
- [MTL](http://www.simunova.com/en/node/24) -- again, this may cost money.

Installing the Intel MKL is very easy, installing Boost not much more difficult (though it's a long time since I tried and the past always looks rosy). I know nothing about Eigen or MTL beyond their existence.

So, first, decide what you really need to install.  If you need an implementation of BLAS, install that.  Then LAPACK.  Then Armadillo.  But your question gives the impression that you are trying to do too many things all at once without the basic understanding of installing libraries on Windows and linking to them.

Oh, and next time you post, use some basic layout and typography to make your question easy to read, I've probably missed half of your points in the thickets of the text you've given us.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   I want to use C++ to do some matrix calculation, so I searched online and find someone comparing several packages that can do my job. So I decided to use Armadillo.Then everything I mentioned all happened to me.    Anyway I'll try the software you recommended. Installing Blas and Lapack is killing me.     And maybe you're right, I'm still confused about how libraries function.    Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) can use MKL, as MKL is essentially a high-speed variant of LAPACK. 

Directly calling MKL or LAPACK functions is an absolute pain -- this is why Armadillo was created, as it provides an easy to use abstraction layer.

Comment: Wow, I'd never noticed that calling MKL or LAPACK functions is painful.

Comment: For most people LAPACK and MKL is far too verbose, and requires manual memory management. That might be ok for very low level stuff, but for algorithm design and experimentation it's simply too error prone.  For example, here's the prototype for calculating an SVD via LAPACK: void dgesvd(char* jobu, char* jobvt, int* m, int* n, double* a, int* lda, double* s, double* u, int* ldu, double* vt, int* ldvt, double* work, int* lwork, int* info).  Compare this with Armadillo's far more user-friendly prototype: svd(mat& U, vec& S, mat& V, mat& X);

Comment: Although a bit late, I must agree with @mtall here. I have been fighting with BLAS and LAPACK for too long. Armadillo has allowed me, with a user friendly syntax, to develop my calculus applications much faster than before, while at the same time taking advantage of some of the fast subroutines provided by LAPACK and BLAS.

Answer (score -1):

You can find answers for all your questions, u need just to read le file README.txt in the armadillo file, inside u will find the sitewebs showing you the addresses you need to download LAPACK and BLAS and also how to install them.